# Using State Variables in Inline Styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I would like to use a state variable in my inline styling as such:

```
const styles = {
progressText1: {
    fontSize: this.state.text1Size
  }
};

constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      text1Size: "300%"
    };
};
```

...So that I can reset it on window resize. I am getting the error "undefined has no properties".  Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll probably have to define it inside your render.

Comment: please include the whole class and place you have tried to use this state variable

Comment: Currently, I haven't tried changing text1Size yet besides initializing it in the constructor, and using it to set the fontSize in progressText1 as above. Does that help?

Comment: `this.state` probably doesn't exist yet. which is why it's `undefined`. move `const styles` into your `render` function and it'll work.

Comment: are you using classes or the `create` style. need more information, otherwise based on what you've posted, you should be receiving syntax errors in the first place.

Comment: @Jessie can you show complete part where you are defining the style ? and paste the complete error message also.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! (I moved const styles into render() per A. Lau)

Comment: Why not do this in css instead with a media query?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `const styles` into your render function, just before your `return`

It may look like this:

```
render() {
  const styles = {
    progressText1: {
      fontSize: this.state.text1Size
    }
  }; 
  return (
    <div style={styles.progressText1}></div>
  )  
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that you had it working before (mentioned by @A. Lau in the above comment conversation, which is long so I couldn't see it at first). However, I was just trying to help!